# Why error "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock"? (WaitGroup and channels)

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to make the numbers 1 through 9 printed to the console in order. I am trying to play around with the goroutines and the channel, but why am I getting the error: fatal error: all goroutines are sleeping - dead end!.

Can you please tell me what is the problem? How can I do it differently?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)

        ch := make(chan int)
        ch2 := make(chan int)
        ch3 := make(chan int)
    
    go func() {
        for _, value := range []int{1, 4, 7} {
            <-ch
            fmt.Println(value)
            ch2 <- 0
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for _, value := range []int{2, 5, 8} {
            <-ch2
            fmt.Println(value)
            ch3 <- 0
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for _, value := range []int{3, 6, 9} {
            <-ch3 
            fmt.Println(value)
            ch <- 0
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Put a value onto the `ch` channel (`ch <- 0`) from your main go routine, right before `wg.Wait()`.

Comment: you prgram is deadlocking because all goroutines, including main, are blocked waiting on something. Mre specifically, the routines the program is spawning are trying to read from channels that are never wrote. `ch` is written if `ch3` was written, `ch3` is written if `ch2`  was written, `ch2` is written if `ch` was written, and (see the recursivity) `ch` is written if `ch3` was written. Having a preliminary write as Tim Cooper suggested unlock the situation.

Answer (score -1):

because in the init unbuffered channel, if you pull the item from a empty channel, it will be block. so what you need to do is to send a signal to ch in main goroutine before it wait.